# How to select date records from a table with leap and non-leap year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I create a sql-server query that ignores 29-of February in a non-leap year and include 29-of February in leap year. (Assuming I have a column in a table with dates from 2000-01-01 to 2016-12-31 for example)

At the moment I have this but it completely removes the leap years.

```
SELECT uid, CONVERT(DATE,CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,day) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                CAST(29 AS VARCHAR(2))) AS code_date, [29] AS code  FROM [data]
                WHERE DATEPART(mm,day) <> 2  AND NOT (ISDATE(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,day) AS char(4)) + '0229') = 1)
```

However, I only want to remove all 29th of February in every year except a leap year.

Comment: you want a list of dates? or know if a year is leap or not?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  The `date` data type doesn't support Feb 29th in non-leap years, so I can figure out what you really want to do.

Comment: The dates in my database are not clean and they include 28 and 29 for all leap and non-leap years. What I want is to select only the dates that includes all years but ignores 29,30&31 for non-leap year and 30&31 for leap year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out and here is the answer

```
SELECT uid, CONVERT(DATE,CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,mydate) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                CAST(29 AS VARCHAR(2))) AS code_date, [29] AS code  FROM [data]
                WHERE DATEPART(mm,mydate) <> 2  OR (ISDATE(CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,mydate) AS char(4)) + '0229') = 1)
```

This selects only 29th of February if only the date is a leap year and excludes 29th of February in non-leap year.

Comment: Have you considered fixing the data in the database? Why do you have rows in the database that is by design wrong and must be ignored?

Comment: The data was imported into the database from another source (excel) and it includes incorrect dates

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server knows what years are leap years :)

```
select isdate('2/29/2015')
select isdate('2/29/2016')
```

> The return value of **ISDATE** depends on the settings set by **SET
>   DATEFORMAT**, **SET LANGUAGE** and Configure the default language Server
>   Configuration Option.

[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/02/28/sql-server-detecting-leap-year-in-t-sql-using-sql-server-2012-iif-eomonth-and-concat-function/) is a function to tell you if the year is a leap year:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsLeapYear (@year INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN(IIF(DATEPART(dd,(EOMONTH(CONCAT(@year,'0201')))) = 29,1,0))
END
GO
```

You could just create a calendar table or use it in a CTE as noted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291758/6167855):

```
--notice 2/29/2016 but no 2/29/2015
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20150201',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20160306';

SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```