# Expand dates for table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I'd like to get better sense of the historical inventory of my objects table.
Thus `Objects` has basically three relevant columns:

```
car_id, incoming_date, outgoing_date
```

Fine, my objects are cars.

For graphing purposes, I'd like to expand the dates on which each car was held.

So the resulting table would look like:

`car_id`, `held_date` and where I can get that `held_date` is between `incoming` and `outgoing` for each car.

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server) that creates the dates in between, but I haven't been able to incorporate this with respect to each car. Help.

Also as a side note, I don't have permission to create calendar tables, so hopefully there's a way around that as well.  Thanks.

Comment: hmm, may `held_period` be better?

Comment: Some initial data to make picture more clear and not abstract?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have made yourself a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) which you definitely 100% should because it's horribly useful. You can then just do something like:

```
 SELECT car_id, calendar.date as held_date
 FROM yourtable
     INNER JOIN calendar 
         ON calendar.date BETWEEN yourtable.incoming_date and yourtable.outgoing_date;
```

And I just read you don't have permission. If you could get permission to build a a table to hold a list of dates, then do it. Otherwise... you can get funky and make a recursive CTE to generate a derived table of dates and use that. It's not going to be fast and it makes for some ugly sql:

```
WITH Calendar AS  
(  
  select DATEADD(day, 1, '2010-01-01') as date
  UNION ALL  
  select DATEADD(day, 1, date) 
  from Calendar 
  where date < '2020-12-31'  
)
 SELECT car_id, calendar.date as held_date
     FROM yourtable
         INNER JOIN calendar 
             ON calendar.date BETWEEN yourtable.incoming_date and yourtable.outgoing_date
     OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```