# Need your assistance with a SQL Server query to get result days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I display the query in such a way to show each day between date?

```
SELECT job.wo_id
FROM [MES].[MESDB].[dbo].[job] AS job
WHERE job.init_sched_ent_id = 227 
  AND job.sched_start_time_local >= @paramStartDate
  AND job.sched_finish_time_local <= @paramEndDate
```

I can select each day separately by function from this post but I don't know how to combines these two tables.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44671808/8853661

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This doesn't *look* like mysql

Comment: That seem like MSSQL not MySQL please edit the tag accordingly

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dates in mySql and cross join with your select.

The good description is here : [generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)