# nested list in sql

Tags: sql

I have 2 lists, one is a list of master list assets, and the second is a list of bookings for those assets on discrete dates.

a simplified version of the asset table is shown below. this has a list of all asset id's and the type/model of asset they are

| AssetId | AssetType |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | model1 |
| 2 | model1 |
| 3 | model2 |
| 4 | model1 |
| 5 | model3 |

and the bookings table is like this

| Date | AssetId |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | 1 |
| 01/01/22 | 5 |
| 03/01/22 | 3 |
| 03/01/22 | 4 |
| 03/01/22 | 2 |

and I want to produce an output that shows count of all assets grouped by their model type in use every day in specific like this

| Date | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | Model1 | 1 |
| 01/01/22 | Model2 | 0 |
| 01/01/22 | Model3 | 1 |
| 02/01/22 | Model1 | 0 |
| 02/01/22 | Model2 | 0 |
| 02/01/22 | Model3 | 0 |
| 03/01/22 | Model1 | 2 |
| 03/01/22 | Model2 | 1 |
| 03/01/22 | Model3 | 0 |

I can easily generate an SQL query to produce a list that shows me which models are in use on specific day but not include the ones that aren't being used or entries for dates when no assets are in use.

Comment: You need to outer-join to a distinct list of models and dates, search Google for "calendar Table"

Comment: Does it answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54825778/how-to-get-missing-dates-with-0-value-in-sql-server ?

Comment: I have tried a calendar table but cannot get the joins correct. this is the code I am running

Comment: SELECT CalendarDate as bookingdate, r.ResModel, count(r.ResModel) as Count
  FROM [AssetMaster].dbo.[Calendar] c
  left join [AssetMaster].dbo.[uk-assets-new] a on c.CalendarDate = convert(datetime, a.ResDate, 103)
  right join [Resource-Master] r on a.ResCode = r.ResCODE
  where r.ResType = 'Camera'
  group by c.calendardate, r.ResModel