# Return 0 values where corresponding type is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

I need a select query where I get amount of visits, type of visit to sort it and in which dates this happend.

My problem is that I dont get 0s at times where there are no visits.

I am using this code:

```
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfVisits,
               CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(dateOfVisit AS DATE), 121)) AS dateOfVisit,
               typeOfVisit
        FROM WEB
        WHERE dateOfVisit >= '1-1-2021'
        AND dateOfVisit <= '1-31-2021'
        GROUP BY CAST(dateOfVisit AS DATE), typeOfVisit
        ORDER BY CAST(dateOfVisit AS DATE)

/*i am converting and casting the date for other reasons that i need in 
my API/frontend and i also get the condition of date from api 1-1-2021 
and 1-31-2021 are just for sample*/
```

and with this **i get the following results**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC6r1.jpg

The columns Follow as:  numberOfVisits | dateOfVisit  |  typeOfVisit

As you can see I have **4 types**.
The first 3 rows contain types 2,3,4 but not 1; I want to have an extra row here with **value 0**, same date and type 1.

The actual value 0 is also not written in the database and neither is null

The desired result would be like this:

```
0   2021-01-04  1
1   2021-01-04  2
10  2021-01-04  3
2   2021-01-04  4
```

and if the result would only show that there were visits of type 2 then it would be something like this:

```
0   2021-01-04  1
1   2021-01-04  2
0   2021-01-04  3
0   2021-01-04  4
```

UPDATE:

So i did what i think is a calander table without actualy creating one and i do get the correct format of data but now my count is way off... let me show you

the query :

```
        DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '1-1-2021',
                @MaxDate DATE = '1-31-2021';
        
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberOfVisits,
               CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(b.VisitDate AS DATE), 121)) AS dateOfVisit,
               a.typeOfVisit
        FROM WEB a
        CROSS JOIN WEB b
        WHERE b.VisitDate >= @MinDate
        AND b.VisitDate <= @MaxDate
        GROUP BY CAST(b.VisitDate AS DATE), a.typeOfVisit
        ORDER BY CAST(b.VisitDate AS DATE)
```

and the result of query : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrSpy.jpg

As you can see the dates and types can all be seen now but the count is huge and if dont do cross join then the dates with no count cant be seen again... I have no clue what goes wrong can you please help me ?

Comment: You can generate a date range and then join to that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)

Comment: Two columns in your resultset named "typeOfVisit" is not a good start. Pay attention to the details. A date is not a "type of visit" either. Don't format dates (or numbers anything else) in the query - that is better done in your presentation layer. Why do you cast to DATE? Is your column Datetime? If so, your WHERE clause is incorrect.

Comment: Yes my bad i  misstyped it here i corrected it but i convert it , beacouse lower i have 2 similar querys but for week and year. And as i specified i do it beacouse i have to for my API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it wasnt clear enough what i wanted in my question, but i managed to come to a solution with case in my select.
If anyone is interested in the solution i came up with, here is how i wrote the select with everything else the same as in the original question.

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TypeOfVisit = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) VisitType1,    
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't count if there is no table record of date. You need to have calendar table with every date to start select from then left join your visit table and count.

It would be something like this:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Calendar') is not null drop table #Calendar

create table #Calendar (adDate date)

declare @dDate date = '2021-01-01'
while @dDate <= '2021-01-31'
begin
    insert into #Calendar (adDate)
    select @dDate

    set @dDate = dateadd(DAY, 1, @dDate)
end

select
    c.adDate,
    w.typeOfVisit,
    COUNT(w.visit) as VisitCount

from #Calendar c
left join web w on w.dateOfVisit = c.adDate
group by 
    c.adDate,
    w.typeOfVisit
order by
    c.adDate
```

If you want to have 0 visits by type also, not just by day then you can do it like this:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Calendar') is not null drop table #Calendar

create table #Calendar (adDate date, anTypeOfVisit int)

declare 
    @dDate date = '2021-01-01',
    @nTypeOfVisit int
while @dDate <= '2021-01-31'
begin
    set @nTypeOfVisit = 1
    while @nTypeOfVisit <=4
    begin
        insert into #Calendar (adDate, anTypeOfVisit)
        select @dDate, @nTypeOfVisit

        set @nTypeOfVisit = @nTypeOfVisit + 1
    end

    set @dDate = dateadd(DAY, 1, @dDate)
end

select
    c.adDate,
    c.anTypeOfVisit,
    COUNT(w.dateofvisit) as VisitCount

from #Calendar c
left join web w on w.dateOfVisit = c.adDate and w.typeofvisit = c.anTypeOfVisit

group by 
    c.adDate,
    c.anTypeOfVisit
order by
    c.adDate,
    c.anTypeOfVisit
```

Comment: I do not exactly know what you mean.... i do have date records in a specific column in the table and also i don't have any issues regarding dates. I think the easiest way to solve this would be with CASE but i simply don't know where to start

Comment: CASE will not help you. The link given in first comment has code that can generate a calendar (1 row per date within the range you desire). This can be done dynamically for a single query. But it is better to have an actual calendar table since it has so many uses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table that contains a row for each visit type for each date. Then do a left join to bring in the counts from your actual data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Visit 
CREATE TABLE #Visit (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,DateOfVisit Date,TypeOfVisit int)
INSERT INTO #Visit
VALUES ('2021-01-04',2),('2021-01-04',3),('2021-01-04',3),('2021-01-04',4);

WITH cte_DistinctVisitDate AS (
    SELECT DateOfVisit
    FROM #Visit
    WHERE DateOfVisit BETWEEN '2020-01-04' AND '2021-01-04' /*Always use YYYY-MM-DD for params as it is culture-agnostic*/
    GROUP BY DateOfVisit
),
cte_TypePerDate AS (
    /*One row for each type on each visit date*/
    SELECT DateOfVisit,TypeOfVisit
    FROM cte_DistinctVisitDate
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)) AS B(TypeOfVisit) /*I am hard coding raw data, but you should use lookup table that contains each visit type*/
),
cte_VisitCount  AS (
    /*Actual counts, but only lists visit types with visits*/
    SELECT DateOfVisit,TypeOfVisit,VisitCnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM #Visit
    GROUP BY DateOfVisit,TypeOfVisit
)

SELECT A.DateOfVisit,A.TypeOfVisit,VisitCnt = ISNULL(B.VisitCnt,0)
FROM cte_TypePerDate AS A
LEFT JOIN cte_VisitCount AS B
    ON A.DateOfVisit = B.DateOfVisit
    AND A.TypeOfVisit = B.TypeOfVisit
```