# Insert multiple rows from a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert multipe rows with one for each date in a date range

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Booked] (
    [BookedId] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BookedFor] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [BookedWhen] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [DeskName] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

From a single statement I want to insert multiple rows in the case below 6 rows one for each date from the following information

```
Declare
  @StartDate smalldatetime = '2022-01-01'
, @EndDate   smalldatetime = '2022-01-06'
, @BookedFor nvarchar(50)  = 'Mr Smith'
, @DeskName  varchar(10)   = '3'
```

To have row that look like

| BookedId | BookedFor | BookedWhen | DeskName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mr Smith | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| 2 | Mr Smith | 2022-01-02 | 3 |
| 3 | Mr Smith | 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| 4 | Mr Smith | 2022-01-04 | 3 |
| 5 | Mr Smith | 2022-01-05 | 3 |
| 6 | Mr Smith | 2022-01-01 | 3 |

Any pointers?

Comment: Use a tally or Numbers table.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE [#Booked] (
    [BookedId] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BookedFor] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [BookedWhen] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [DeskName] [varchar] (10) NOT NULL
)


Declare
  @StartDate smalldatetime = '2022-01-01'
, @EndDate   smalldatetime = '2022-01-06'
, @BookedFor nvarchar(50)  = 'Mr Smith'
, @DeskName  varchar(10)   = '3'


;WITH Dates(day) AS 
(
    SELECT CAST(@StartDate as Date) as day
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, day) as Date) as day
    FROM Dates
    WHERE CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, day) as Date) < @EndDate
)
INSERT INTO #Booked 
SELECT @BookedFor, [day], @DeskName FROM dates;

SELECT * FROM #Booked
```

[Create days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server)