# Calculate time difference bewteen 2 datetime excluding weekend in days hours minutes seconds format

Tags: sql, postgresql, php-carbon

I want to calculate the time difference between two datetime. Saturday and sunday need to be excluded from the calculation.

For exemple difference between `2023-01-10 15:12:24` and `2023-01-01 10:34:36` is `6 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48 seconds` according to PHP carbon.

```
<?php
require 'vendor\carbon\autoload.php';
use Carbon\CarbonImmutable;
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;


$created = CarbonImmutable::parse("2023-01-02 10:34:36");
$firstResponse = CarbonImmutable::parse("2023-01-10 15:12:24");
$diffInSeconds = 0;
$step = $created;

while ($step < $firstResponse) {
    if ($step->isWeekend()) {
        $step = $step->next('Monday');

        continue;
    }

    $nextStep = min($firstResponse, $step->addDay()->startOfDay());

    $diffInSeconds += $step->diffInSeconds($nextStep);
    $step = $nextStep;
}

echo CarbonInterval::seconds($diffInSeconds)->cascade()->forHumans(); //6 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48 seconds
```

The goal is to calculate this value using SQL.

I've come to this following query :

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (
  SELECT '2023-01-02 10:34:36'::timestamp AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM date) IN (6, 7) THEN date + INTERVAL '1 day'*(8-EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM date))
           ELSE date + INTERVAL '1 DAY'
         END
  FROM date_range
  WHERE date + INTERVAL '1 DAY' < '2023-01-10 15:12:24'::timestamp
)
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    FLOOR(diff / 86400), ' days ',
    FLOOR((diff % 86400) / 3600), ' hours ',
    FLOOR((diff % 3600) / 60), ' minutes ',
    FLOOR(diff % 60), ' seconds'
  ) AS duration
FROM (
  SELECT
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-01-10 15:12:24'::timestamp - MAX(date))::interval) AS diff
  FROM date_range
) t;
```

Output :

```
----------------------------------------
| duration                             |
----------------------------------------
| 0 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48 seconds |
----------------------------------------
```

I don't understand why days has value equal to 0.

How can I fix the days value ?

Fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3V6QVdE1PPETKS6yN33zdE/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you always get 0 days is because you selecting `MAX(date)` which turns out to be `2023-01-10 10:34:36` (the first value that satisfies your exit condition) which is 0 days from `2023-01-10 15:12:24`. Perhaps you should select MIN(date). I am not even sure that is valid for all timestamps not if the start and/or end dates specified fall on a weekend?   
But why are you messing around with `epoch` from an interval then the "complicated" date/time calculations. Your process centers around 2 hard-coded timestamps. The subtraction of 2 timestamps gives an `interval` then you can directly extract each field. Your query reduces to: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SsNKfkmR))

```
with parms (start_date, end_date) as
       ( select '2023-01-02 10:34:36'::timestamp          --- as parameter $1
              , '2023-01-10 15:12:24'::timestamp          --- as parameter $2
       ) 
     , weekend_days (wkend) as 
       ( select sum(case when extract(isodow from d) in (6, 7) then 1 else 0 end) 
           from parms 
           cross join generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') dn(d)
       ) 
select concat( extract( day from diff)     , ' days '     
             , extract( hours from diff)   , ' hours '   
             , extract( minutes from diff) , ' minuets '  
             , extract( seconds from diff)::int , ' seconds '
             )
   from ( 
          select (end_date-start_date)- ( wkend * interval '1 day') diff
            from parms 
            join weekend_days on true
         ) sq;
```

You can even wrap the query in a SQL function and completely hide it away.

```
create or replace function diff_without_weekend( start_date_in timestamp
                                               , end_date_in timestamp)
  returns text 
 language sql
 as $$
     with weekend_days (wkend) as 
          ( select sum(case when extract(isodow from d) in (6, 7) then 1 else 0 end) 
              from generate_series(start_date_in, end_date_in, interval '1 day') dn(d)
          ) 
    select CONCAT( extract( day from diff)     , ' days '     
                 , extract( hours from diff)   , ' hours '   
                 , extract( minutes from diff) , ' minuets '  
                 , extract( seconds from diff)::int , ' seconds ')
      from ( select (end_date_in -start_date_in )- ( wkend * interval '1 day') diff
               from weekend_days
           ) sq;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting question which completely distracted me from work! This question is similar and could be useful to you:[Get all dates between two dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server) .
I think the recommendation of building a calendar table would help you a lot!

To directly answer your question I think it you need to change from max to min, as I have, here:

```
FROM (
SELECT
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ('2023-01-10 15:12:24'::timestamp - MIN(date))::interval) AS diff
  FROM date_range) t;
```

However even with this you return 8 days when I think the answer should be 7....

I'm not overly familiar with the recursive so I went for something like the below. The case statement can definitely be optimised.  {note I'm snowflake dialect}

```
SET start_date = '2023-01-02 10:34:36';
SET end_date = '2023-01-10 15:12:24';
WITH DateRange(DateData) AS
    (
    SELECT $start_date::DATe as Date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAYS ,1,DateData)::DATE
    FROM DateRange
    WHERE DateData < $end_date
    )
,date_array AS (
    SELECT datedata
            , DAYOFWEEK(datedata) AS day_index
            , dayname(datedata) AS day_name
            , $start_date
            , $end_date
    FROM daterange
)

SELECT
       $start_date
       , substring($start_date ,12,8)::TIME as start_time
       , $end_date
       , substring($end_date ,12,8)::TIME as end_time
       , HOUR(end_time) - HOUR(start_time) as hours
       , MINUTE(end_time) - MINUTE(start_time) as minutes
       , SECOND(end_time) - SECOND(start_time) as seconds
       , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN day_index NOT IN (6,0) THEN  datedata END ) as  days
       , CONCAT (
           CASE WHEN hours < 0 THEN days -1 ELSE days END , ' days ' ,

           CASE
               WHEN minutes < 0 AND hours < 0 THEN 24 + hours  -1
               WHEN minutes > 0 AND hours < 0 THEN 24 + hours
               WHEN minutes < 0 AND hours > 0 THEN   hours -1
                   ELSE hours END
           , ' hours ' ,
           CASE
               WHEN seconds < 0 AND minutes < 0 THEN 60 + minutes  -1
               WHEN seconds > 0 AND minutes < 0 THEN 60 + minutes
               WHEN seconds < 0 AND minutes > 0 THEN   minutes -1
                   ELSE minutes END

           , ' minutes ' ,
           CASE WHEN seconds <0 THEN 60 + seconds ELSE seconds END , ' seconds') as output
FROM date_array
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Output :

---

### | output                           |

### | 7 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48 seconds |

Comment: Also just for my curiosity, could you explain what this it doing: 
`date + INTERVAL '1 day'*(8-EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM date))`
I think you're doing the `date + 1 * (8 - ([1-7])` is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Since your difference time is calculated by extract `end date` to the `MAX(date)` - which its value is same date as `end date` or the last working date before `end date`, so difference days value could not be calculated correctly.

You could achieve your desired result by using below query.

1. Generating date series from `start date` to `end date` by using [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function, then get only working days from this series.
2. For each working date in date series, calculate `working time` per each date (data type of `working time` will be Postgres's [interval](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-interval/)).
3. Then calculating total `working time` of all working dates in date series.

```
SET intervalstyle = 'postgres_verbose'; -- format display style for interval

WITH date_range AS 
      (SELECT '2023-01-02 10:34:36'::timestamp AS start_date
            , '2023-01-10 15:12:24'::timestamp AS end_date),
     date_series AS
      (SELECT  d as date
            ,  (CASE
                  WHEN start_date::date = d THEN interval '1 day' + (d - start_date)::interval
                  WHEN end_date::date = d THEN  (end_date - d)::interval
                  ELSE interval '1 day'
               END) AS working_time
       FROM date_range 
            CROSS JOIN generate_series(start_date::date, end_date::timestamp, interval '1 day') d
       WHERE EXTRACT (ISODOW FROM  d) BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
       
SELECT SUM(working_time) AS working_time
FROM date_series;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/AV9HMNEM).