Include missing dates between dates
SELECT CAST(from_time AS DATE) AS date,
       COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS quantity
FROM planned
WHERE from_time >=  '2024-06-01 00:00:00.000'
  AND from_time <=  '2024-08-09 00:00:00.000'
  AND line='Line1'
  AND PlantName='Luminous'
GROUP BY CAST(from_time AS DATE)

The above query returns date and quantity. I want the result date should include all the missing dates between the two dates-from_time with quantity 0 for missing dates. For example, if date 2024-08-03 is not available in the records, the result from the above query will not include that date. I want the result date to also include 2024-08-03 with the quantity 0. I'm using SQL Server. How will I achieve this?

using calendar table

This is a very common question, solved many times before. Take look and have a go.

FROM Calendar LEFT JOIN planned. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server

What is your SQL Server version (SELECT @@VERSION;)

@YitzhakKhabinsky Microsoft SQL Server 2022

You need to base your query on a calendar. Use an existing calendar table  or Generate a calendar table using the best strategy for your version of SQL-Server (CTE, GENERATE_SERIES, ...). see Get all dates between two dates in SQL Server .
The FROM should be changed to FROM Calendar LEFT JOIN  planned. Also move all of your planned specific criteria within the LEFT JOIN clause.
--With missing days between range
SELECT c.date,
       COALESCE(SUM(p.quantity),0) AS quantity
FROM 
  (

   --put your Calendar table or generator here
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, value, '2024-06-01') AS [Date]
   FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(DAY ,'2024-06-01', '2024-08-09'))  
  
  ) c

LEFT JOIN  planned p on CAST(p.from_time as date)=c.date
                        AND p.line='Line1'
                        AND p.PlantName='Luminous'

--WHERE clause not needed if you generate only the dates you want
WHERE c.date >=  '2024-06-01 00:00:00.000'
  AND c.date <=  '2024-08-09 00:00:00.000'

GROUP BY c.date

fiddle



date
quantity




2024-06-01 00:00:00.000
0


2024-06-02 00:00:00.000
2


2024-06-03 00:00:00.000
0


2024-06-04 00:00:00.000
0


2024-06-05 00:00:00.000
0


63 other rows ...
0


2024-08-08 00:00:00.000
1


2024-08-09 00:00:00.000
0




As a side note, the WHERE isn't needed here as GENERATE_SERIES is only going to generate the rows you asked for. (Also, qualifying column names is a very good habit).

If from_time has a date record with time part it's not including in the result. For example 2024-08-05 19:00:00.000 is not included in the result. But 2024-08-05 00:00:00.000 is included in the result.

@Ram I added a CAST to cover that scenario

You can create calendar table  and join with your query.
select date,coalesce(quantity,0) as quantity 
from (select dateadd(d,value,cast('2024-06-01' as date)) plandate
    from generate_series(0,datediff(d,'2024-06-01','2024-08-09'))
  )calendar
left join (
SELECT CAST(from_time AS DATE) AS date,
       COALESCE(SUM(quantity),0) AS quantity
FROM planned
WHERE from_time >=  '2024-06-01 00:00:00.000'
  AND from_time <=  '2024-08-09 00:00:00.000'
  AND line='Line1'
  AND PlantName='Luminous'
GROUP BY CAST(from_time AS DATE)
)data on calendar.plandate=data.date


Giving Null values for quantity for missing dates. I want quantity to be 0 for missing dates.

Use coalesce(quantity,0) as quantity.
